# Possible to Bevel a Boolean and a Weight Together?

Tags: modifiers, edges, bevel

I want to be able to bevel the edges created by a Boole modifier, but at the same time respect the original Edges Data of the object (so that not all of the edges are beveled).

Is it possible to do this without applying any modifiers?

[Project File](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/i1ocibxldys60jgnan1yf/Bevel-Boole-How.blend?rlkey=mu951f6etja8xxbice6e2heaj&dl=0)

What I want is to create an object that is an amalgam of the last two images where the bottom is flat but the hole created by the boolean is beveled:

Edge Creases
[image]

Bevel result by Weight
[image]

Bevel result by Angle
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I define a vertex group called "outer" that contains all the vertices from the original Cube, and in the Bevel I say "use the *inverse* -- all vertices *not* in this group:

[image]

[image]

Some miscellaneous thoughts:

If you want other edges to also be beveled, remove them from the "outer" V Group.

If you add vertices, they won't be added to the "outer" group, so you can end up with a mess, unless you decide to Apply the Bevel modifier... meaning you can no longer adjust the parameters like Segments and Amount.

Comment: Hello James, from what I understand he still wants 4 round edges like in picture 2, so you probably need to add a second Bevel with Bevel Weight

Comment: Oh man, I knew the solution had to be simple but I did not know there was an invert button right in front of me!  Thank you, this is huge for me.  Cheers!

Comment: @moonboots -- I gave him just enough rope  ....  ;)